# Как правильно добавить существующий ssh ключ для Bitbucket

Tags: сервер, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-key

Добрый день.
Вопрос в принципе, написан в заголовке, у меня есть ssh ключ на Bitbucket, которым я пользовался на предыдущем компьютере, как мне привязать этот же ключ к новому компьютеру, что бы не создавать новый. В папке ./ssh сейчас нет файлов id_rsa и id_rsa.pub. Мне необходимо сначала создать эти папки, а потом туда скопировать ключ?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Скопируй папку .ssh со старого компьютера на новый, поставь владельца папки и права как на старом и все должно быть как на старом